And selector referencing parent selector twice in SCSS
I want to do in SCSS something quite simple in vanilla CSS: targeting an element that has two classes.
A simplified example is below:
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child child--red"></div>
  <div class="child child--green"></div>
  <div class="child child--red child--green"></div>
</div>

I want to target the child that has both child--green and child--red. I tried stuff like below, but it doesn't work:
.parent {
  & > .child {
    &--red {
      color: red;
    }
    &--green {
      color: green;
    }
    &--red.&--green {
      color: yellow;
    }
  }
}

I understand why that syntax doesn't work, considering how the parent selector works, but I'm wondering if there's an elegant way to do it with the parent selector without having to repeat the child like:
.parent {
  & > .child {
    &--red {
      color: red;
    }
    &--green {
      color: green;
      &.child--red{
        color: yellow;
      }
    }
    // OR
    &--red.child--green {
      color: yellow;
    }
  }
}

Any idea? Thanks!

If you want to maintain that syntax, there are two options (the first is not ideal performance-wise, would probably make sense to just write it out as suggested in the other answer)
Option 1 - Using the :is selector allows you to use both on one line:
&--red:is(&--green){
  color: yellow;
}

Option 2 - A bit less fluid and not the best to look at, but you can store the name in a variable and reference it this way so that it's still managed in one place:
.parent {
  $childClass: child;
  & > .#{$childClass} {
    &--red {
      color: red;
    }
    &--green {
      color: green;
    }
    &--red.#{$childClass}--green {
      color: yellow;
    }
  }
}


The option 2 probably has more drawbacks readability wise than repeating the child. is is indeed an elegant solution, I didn't know about it, thanks. Although not great if it has a performance hit, I'll need to read a bit about that, a quick search doesn't yield much info about its performance.

From what I've seen looking it up today, :is may actually have a barely any performance hit when used that way, I guess I just assumed it would be slower
